# understand / translating C# event accessor code (particularly += operator) to VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, event-handling

I have this bit of C#-code which I need to translate to VB.

```
private EventHandler something = null;

public event EventHandler Something
{
    add
        { this.something += value; }
    remove
        { this.something -= value; }
}
```

I have come up with this so far (I know it lacks a RaiseEvent-bit):

```
Private _something As EventHandler = Nothing

Public Custom Event Something As EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        AddHandler Me.Something, value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        RemoveHandler Me.Something, value
    End RemoveHandler
End Event
```

When the inner AddHandler is `AddHandler Me._something, value` I am informed that the class does not contain an Event `_something`. Then I came across some example code that appeared to use a construction like the one I posted verbatim.
This however makes VS complain about recursively calling the AddHandler for the Event. So it seems I got the translation of the event accessor code all wrong.

However the EventHandler.Operator `+=` does not exist in VB and *I kind of wonder why it would work in C#, given that the variable `something` is not a collection* of some sort. I guess if I understood this properly I might just come up with something for VB.

Obviously I am rather confused about the situation with Events in .NET, particularly about how C# and VB concepts relate in this case.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: Probably the last quarter of that is most relevant to that code.

Comment: That said, you may be able to use a delegate field internally rather than using a collection and use `Delegate.Combine` internally.  Not sure of the implications of that as it's some time ago that I wrote that blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# allows you to assign directly to a delegate field ("_something") invocation list, but VB doesn't.
The VB equivalent is a little verbose, using Delegate.Combine and Delegate.Remove (I also threw in the RaiseEvent block):

```
Private _something As EventHandler = Nothing

Public Custom Event Something As EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        Me._something = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Me._something, DirectCast(value, EventHandler)), EventHandler)
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        Me._something = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Remove(Me._something, DirectCast(value, EventHandler)), EventHandler)
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Me._something IsNot Nothing Then
            Me._something.Invoke(sender, e)
        End If
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

Comment: @Servy: I think you're correct - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are your special needs for (C#) something field? How do you work with it in the rest of your code? If there are not any special needs, you can just replace the entire block of code with

```
Public Event Something
```

and nothing else.

Equivalent of C# += and -= operators for events are the AddHandler and RemoveHandler keywords that will be placed outside of your class like

```
Dim X As New SomeType
AddHandler X.Something, AddressOf X_Something
...
RemoveHandler X.Something, AddressOf X_Something
```

or using `WithEvents` keyword (just to pin out something you might not be aware of) to omit a lot of AddHandler/RemoveHandler calls. This is not useful when working with collections of SomeType, but it's very useful when working with single instances.

```
Private WithEvents fA, fB As New SomeType

Private Sub Handle_Something Handles fA.Something, fB.Something
   'Handle the event
End Sub
```

Comment: I have just gone with assigning the EventHandler directly which for now seems to work quite fine. Thanks a lot for your input though.

I guess what I still really don't get is why `+=` works in C# in this case, where it is not used on a collection type.

Comment: Just consider C# operator += for events as equivalent to AddHandler in VB. C-like languages prefere short code before readable code. Under the hood, there is a collection of theese handlers anyway.